# Multiple php isset in one page

Tags: php, ajax, pagination

I'm trying to achieve multiple pagination in one page. 
The pagination for all the results, is working. 
But except from the main results, i want to include different options.
For example, in the image below i have three more options, 
**Newest**, **Reputation**, **Oldest** 
[image]

So, i want multiple pagination for all these options. 
In the page that i want to display the results, i have multiple `isset()`, in order to achieve that.

```
<div id='paginationUsers'>
  <?php
  //for all the results that displaying first.
  if(isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
  } else {
    $page = 1;
  }
  echo "<input type='hidden' id='pageAll' value='".$page."'>";
  // for the Newest results
  if(isset($_GET['pageNewest'])) {
    $pageNewest = $_GET['pageNewest'];
    } else {
    $pageNewest = 1;
  }
  echo "<input type='hidden' id='newPage' value='".$pageNewest."'>";
  //for the Oldest results
  if(isset($_GET['pageOldest'])) {
    $pageOldest = $_GET['pageOldest'];
  } else {
    $pageOldest = 1;
  }
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='oldPage' value='".$pageOldest."'>";
    //for the Reputation results
    if(isset($_GET['pageReputation'])) {
      $pageReputation = $_GET['pageReputation'];
    } else {
      $pageReputation = 1;
    }
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='reputationPage' value='".$pageReputation."'>";
  ?>
</div>
```

Ofcourse, in that way cannot work as you can see in the code.  
So, is it possible to include multiple `isset` in one page?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<?php

function getGET($name) {
    if (isset($_GET[$name]) {
    return $_GET[$name];
    } else {
    return 1;
    }
}

function genInput($id, $name) {
    return "<input type='hidden' id='". $id ."' value='". getGET($name) ."'>";
}

echo "<input type='hidden' id='pageAll' value='". getGet('page')."'>";

echo genInput('newPag', 'pageNewest');
echo genInput('oldPage', 'pageOldest');
echo genInput('', 'pageReputation');
```

Comment: I try that,,  the pagination with id pageAll is working, but in the pagination for example with id newPag, is working only the first page, when i click to the second page, it displays the results from the first page with the id pageAll. So, it seems again that when is not isset the first id with pageAll it returns to 1.

Comment: check URL from where you got GET values.

Comment: URL's are correct. In the bottom of this page, i call a javascript function to display the results from the option with the id pageAll. So, i wonder if that is the problem and when i click to the second page the id with pageNewest, then id with pageAll returns to 1. If that is the case, i don't know how to handle this.

Comment: check DB query, where fro you got rulults